# Access host postgres from docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, centos, centos7

I have a CentOS 7 server, on which individually postgres (port 5432) and docker is running.

Currently I am trying to access postgres database from my docker container. But I am getting the below error:

````
    at Connection.parseE (/usr/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:604:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/usr/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:401:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:121:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  name: 'error',
  length: 161,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '28000',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'auth.c',
  line: '489',
  routine: 'ClientAuthentication' }```

I have change pg_hba.conf of my host postgres application that too didn't solve the issue.
Any help will be appreciated.
````

Comment: Please share more information: which port / IP does your postgres server bind to? is postgres also running in a container? Can you share a simple client scenario? e.g. a Dockerfile to build a client that fails to connect to postrges and the commands that you used to start the docker container

Comment: Thanks for the revert. 
1)My postgres runs on port 5432 of host server. 
2)Docker is also configured on same host. 
3)There is no postgres running on any of the docker container.
4) Docker build is successful.
5) Command to run the image:
docker run -d -p 3001:3001 <image name>

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Are you trying to access the postgres server with the IP of the hostmachine? is the Postgres server bound to the IP of the hostmachine? (e.g. not 127.0.0.1 / localhost)

Comment: Yes I am using the IP of the hostmachine to connect.

Comment: Do you have firewall running on your CentOS 7 machine? e.g. firewalld? If so is the postgres port opened in your firewall configuration?

Comment: Yes I do.
How to check whether postgres port is openend from my docker too.

Comment: The container does not have a running firewalld, since containers are only running a single process (best practice at least ;) . To enable access to the postgres on your host you can follow the instructions here: https://serverfault.com/questions/789014/issues-configuring-firewall-rules-for-postgres-on-centos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Clemans for your help, I got the solution. Issue was due to docker network since it was not able to connect to host. Since by default my container was running in docker network bridge. I changed that to run into host which solve my issue. Below is the command which I used to run my container 
`docker run --network=host -d <image name>`

Comment: Great! Thank you for posting the solution to your question :)